# Replace light switch with z wave smart switch

Tags: electrical, smart-switch, z-wave

I'm trying to replace a light switch with a new z wave smart switch. Specifically, the old light switch has 2 black wires and a ground wire attached to it and it is the only switch that controls 1 LED light. The new z wave switch is an Eaton RF9601 and it has 4 output wires: white, black, red and blue. This is the wiring diagram provided with the switch: [image]
And I am a bit confused with how (or if) my scenario is compatible with this z wave switch. I capped the blue switch output and connected the green output to the existing ground wire I had, and connected the black output to one of the existing black wires. The other black wire is what I wasn't sure how to connect. I tried connecting it to the red output and the light comes on but was very dim, when connected to the white output the light was completely off. Any suggestions for the correct way to wire this?

[image]

A = Black Wire

B = Ground

C = Black Wire

D = Neutral?

When connected with A -> Red, B -> Green, C -> Black, D-> White and the light does not come on at all when power is turned back on.

Based on suggestions in comments I tried connecting A -> Black, B -> Green, C -> Red, D-> White and the light flashes and immediately turns off when the power to the switch is turned on.

Adding another picture of box to help clarify:

[image]

Turquoise circles are ends of white wire (D) and red circles are ends of black wires coming into box.

Comment: Can you please post photos of the inside of the box you're trying to install this switch to?

Answer (score 1):

The new smart switch requires a neutral so unless you have a couple white wires wire-nutted together in the box with the switch, you're out of luck using that switch. You'll need to get a switch that doesn't require a neutral.

If you have only two true black wires in the switch box, chances are you have conduit and you could pull some THHN from the ceiling to the switch and bring in a neutral but we'd need more pictures to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

### The white is your neutral, most likely

Given that you have a bundle of at least 2 white wires in your switch box, that is most likely the *neutral* connection that your switch needs to work.  Connect the white wire on the switch to that bundle with an appropriately sized wirenut, and continue wiring the rest of the switch.

Comment: So when I connected the white wire on the switch to the white wire labeled as D in the photo and turned the power back on the light was completely off. So maybe that wire was not the neutral wire?

Comment: @ez4nick  Be sure to connect the black wire from the switch to the always hot black wire in the box.

Comment: @JACK The capped black wires in the back of the box?

Comment: @ez4nick  One of the two black wires from your old switch is always hot. That's the one that goes to your black wire from your new switch. If one of those goes to a group of black wires, then it the always hot.

Comment: @JACK Got it, before I think I had been connecting the black wire labeled as C in my photo to the black switch output. So then C goes to the red switch output and A goes to the black switch output?

Comment: @ez4nick -- yeah, that sounds about right

Comment: Just tried this... And when I turn the power back on the light flashes and then goes off immediately. Assuming that is not a good sign. Running out of ideas here.

Comment: @ez4nick  Follow your C and A  wire back to where they both come into the box.  Follow the white wires that come into the box with those two black wires and see if they are twisted together to form D.

Comment: @JACK added another photo to my original post.. Looks like the white wires that form D come in from 2 separate locations and A and C are separate as well one comes from top and the other bottom

Comment: @ez4nick There are white wires associated with A and C..... where do they end up? are they twisted together?

Comment: @JACK yes it appears to me that those white wires end up twisted together to form D

Comment: @ez4nick -- switch C and A around

Comment: @ez4nick -- if it's not that, then I'd take the switch back and get a new one provided the old switch was the only one controlling this light

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just tried switching C and A and I get nothing.. No light at all. May have to accept defeat on this one unfortunately. Could I have fried the switch with all of the things I've tried along the way? Appreciate all the help with this.

Comment: @ez4nick -- that's what I'm suspecting -- you might have shorted something out and fried the switch in the process

Answer (score 0):

If you have two black wires in switch box it should be two white wires, connected together. One black wire is phase coming from panel, it always hot. Connect it  with black wire of  new switch. Another black wire is going to load. Connect it with red wire. How you need short piece of wire to make a pigtail. One side connect together with white wires, another side with white wire of new switch. Terminate blue wire with wire nut or electrical tape. And connect ground.

Comment: OP _should_ have white wires (i.e. neutral) in the box _unless_, of course, the power goes to the light first, then there's a switch loop running to the switch itself. This was a very common way of wiring switches that has only recently been banned because of the need of modern smart switches to have a neutral at the box.

Comment: @FreeMan It is for sure. If there is no white wires a.k.a. neutral, OP can not connect the switch neutral. My guess it has neutral connected inside the box because two black wires means two cables. Each has black and white wire inside at least. If there is not cable but pipes, the additional wire may be pulled inside. Only  OP knows what's going on.